# Spring - redirect the request handler

Tags: java, spring, rest, redirect

How can I redirect the request handler?
That's what I want:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
        return getUser(100500);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        User user = userService.findById(id);

        if(user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

it is the right decision?

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getUser() {
    return getUser(100500);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Responsebody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    User user = userService.findById(id);

    if(user == null) {
        return new ResponseEntit`enter code here`y<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

you can try this way ,int that way ,you can response User to you page.